# The universe of x and y consists of the numbers 2 and 5. Write a statement logically equivalent to the given statements, without quantifiers.

Tags: logic, logic-translation

> Suppose that the universe of x and y consists of the numbers 2 and 5. Write a statement logically equivalent to the given statement, and which has no quantifiers. Determine the truth value of your statement.
>   i) $\forall x, 10x \leq 50$
>   ii) $\exists y, (2y \lt 6) \rightarrow (y = 3)$
>   iii) $\exists x, \forall y, xy \geq 10$

For i, can I assign $P(x) = 10x \leq 50$ and say $\forall x, 10x \leq 50 \Leftrightarrow P(2) \land P(5)$?

If I can, then could I just do the same for the other two questions?

Comment: ye that seems ok. But are you allowed to form new predicates ?

Comment: @asddf I'm not sure. All the information I have is in the question.

Comment: If you can then its ok just remember to use or for exists.

Answer (score 0):

You could introduce new predicates, but it obscures the evaluation.   Why not just write the following, which make the result obvious?   In the domain of discourse $\{2,5\}$ then:

$$\forall x~(10x\leq 50) ~\iff~ (10\cdot 2\leq 50)\wedge (10\cdot 5\leq 50)$$

Answer (score 0):

> For i, can I assign $P(x) = 10x \leq 50$ and say $\forall x, 10x \leq 50 \Leftrightarrow P(2) \land P(5)$?

You can't use the $\Leftrightarrow$ here, as that is about all possible domains.  So you merely write down what the quantified statement amounts to relative to this specific domain, which is $10 \cdot 2 \le 50 \land 10 \cdot 5 \le 50$